# Python dataframe merge with multiple different keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2 dataframes table1 with columns (Amount, A, B ) and table2 with columns (Amount, C, D), how would I be able to join the two tables together using the merge function with the condition table1.A= table2.D and table1.B = table2.C?

I have looked up the merge function and it states it have the left_on and right_on only.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
df_table1.merge(df_table2, how='inner', left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['D', 'C'])
```

You can pass a list to left_on/right_on within the merge function. Ordering is important.

There's also left_index/right_index if you want to join on either DataFrame index.